# Issue with Custom URL scheme and messages app in iOS

Tags: iphone

I have registered an Custom URL scheme in my application. From server i send an SMS to the phone with the message starting with the custom URL scheme. example myapp://mymessageToApplication

When the SMS reaches the inbox, the messages application does not receognize the above message as a link. So, i am unable to click on the message to start by application. This happens everytime i delete the application and reinstall the application. But, when i restart my phone,  the messages application recognizes the message as a link and i can click on the link to start my application. After that it all fine until i delete the current application and re-install it again through xCode on my test phone.

Does anyone aced similar issue? can anyone suggest me what could be wrong?

To add, i can type the message myapp://mymessageToApplication in browser to launch my application. It works always. So, the custom URL is registered fine. Only the messages application is not picking it up until i restart the phone.

Answer (score 1):

I have filed a bug in Apple and they have replied for that. They ahve agreed that it is a known issue and they are working on it.

Below is the reply from them

This is a follow up to Bug ID# 10166363.  After further investigation it has been determined that this is a known issue, which is currently being investigated by engineering.  This issue has been filed in our bug database under the original Bug ID# 10053369. The original bug number being used to track this duplicate issue can be found in the State column, in this format:  Duplicate/OrigBug#.

Thank you for submitting this bug report. We truly appreciate your assistance in helping us discover and isolate bugs.

Comment: Does anybody have any update on these bugs? I tried searching Radar for them but neither of these bug id numbers returned a result (Include Inactive Problems is set to yes)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to only kill and restart the messages application instead of restarting your iPhone completely?

I guess that's only because the Messages application only check which custom URL schemes are registered when it launches (and not when it is already launched but in background and is only brought to forground). Just a guess but it might be a probable explanation

*(and if it is, I don't think there is anything you can do except file a bug to Apple... but check it first)*

Comment: Just a restart of messages application wasn't suffice. I had to restart the phone.

Comment: Ow. You probably should file a bug to Apple then, I'm afraid that's on them :( http://bugreport.apple.com